# Remove a site column from Document Library

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, document-library, site-column

I was trying something w.r.t search result templates and I included following Site columns in my document library:

```
'Target Folder' , 'Target Library' , 'Target Path'
```

Now I am not able to delete / deselect these columns from my Document library. Is it because the document library has documents?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

they sound like custom fields. When you say deselect you mean within the view?

to remove them if they are not visible within the main list settings area... first check to see if you have any content types:

you should have at the top a load of urls for your list settings, below you should then have a list of content types that are linked to the list and below that you would have the list items that are within the list.

Click on the content type, it would direct you to another page... from there you can click on the fields to hide, or remove... you can also set them to required or non-required.

Removing them from the parent content type would be global! doing it from the method above is only for that given list!

Comment: Thanks Ali.
I can edit the view but the columns still appear in "edit doc" properties.
These are "Site Columns" and I had added these using "Add from existing site columns" option in "Document Library" settings. I noticed these columns have latched to the content type "Document". So, the "List Content Type -Document" has these 3 additional columns & its parent "Site Content Type - Document" does not have these columns. There is no option to delete these columns in "List Content type", nor cannot i delete the List Content Type. I fear I will have to delete this Document Library.

Answer (score 1):

Any document or folder in a library currently using a column will make it locked it for deletion. When trying to delete the column you should get an information message informing you that the column is in use.

If the column is on a content type in the library, then first remove it from the content type and then from the library.

And of course this is if no Document or folder is using the column. If they are start by deleting them and then retry removing you column from the library.